# Get list from last row of DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame looking like this:

```
             28    91    182
Date                        
2017-09-07  0.97  1.05  1.15
2017-09-08  0.95  1.04  1.14
2017-09-11  0.96  1.06  1.16
2017-09-12  0.99  1.04  1.16
2017-09-13  0.99  1.04  1.16
```

From this DataFrame i would like to get a list of the values of the last row.

```
[0.99, 1.04, 1.16]
```

I attempted to use

```
np.array(tbill.iloc[-1:].values).tolist()
```

which returns

```
[[0.99, 1.04, 1.16]]
```

but feels overly complicated.

Is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: You could have done `np.array(tbill.iloc[-1:].values).tolist()[0]` (but answer below is better).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just slice the underlying array.

```
df.values[-1].tolist()
```

which yields

```
[0.99, 1.04, 1.16]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just:

```
df.iloc[-1].tolist()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3))

print(df.iloc[-1].tolist())
[-0.3000246004134489, -0.3626924316159151, 0.9523820239889618]
```

@miradulo's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221714/7954504) will actually be faster in this case, I believe because indexing a NumPy array is significantly faster than indexing a DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called `tail` that you can access rows backward.

```
df.tail(1).values.tolist()   # get last row and its values
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html